# Opening a Report with a Lightning Web Component

Tags: lightning-web-components, reporting

I am trying to write a lwc that will allow users to enter a reporting url and and choose 2 parameters from a combo-box. Based on their selection, I'm trying to pass the parameters to a report url.  I can't get it to open a report.  Here is the html:

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="Get Report">
    <lightning-input type="url" name="ReportURL" label="Enter Report URL"></lightning-input>
    <lightning-combobox name="Parameter 1" label="Parameter 1" value={param1} options={options}></lightning-combobox>
    <lightning-combobox name="Parameter 2" label="Parameter 2" value={param2} options={options}></lightning-combobox>
    <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Get Report" title="Get Report" onclick={handleClick} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
  </lightning-card>
```

Here is my js file:

```
import { LightningElement, track, api} from 'lwc';
import Id from '@salesforce/user/Id';
export default class CpReportViewer extends LightningElement {

@track reportURL;
@track param1;
@track param2;
@api recordId;
@api userId;
 connectedCallback(){
  this.userId = Id;
 }


 get options(){
  return[
{label: 'None', value: 'None'},
{label: 'Current User', value: 'Current User'},
{label: 'Current Record', value: 'Current Record'},
  ];
```

}

```
 handleClick(event) {
this.ReportUrl = event.target.value;
console.log('Am i getting the URL', this.Reporturl);
this.param1 = event.target.value;
this.param2 = event.target.value;
if(this.Param1 === 'Current Record' && this.Param2 === 'None'){
    this.Param1 = this.recordId;
    } else if (this.Param1 === 'Current Record' && this.Param2 === 'Current User'){
      this.Param1 = this.recordId;
      this.Param2 = this.userId;
    } else if (this.Param1 === 'Current User' && this.Param2 === 'None'){
      this.Param1 = this.userId;
    } else if(this.Param1 === 'Current User' && this.Param2 === 'Current Record'){
      this.Param1 = this.userId;
      this.Param2 = this.recordId;
    }
if(this.Param1 === 'None'){
      location.href="this.ReportUrl";
     } else if (this.param1 === 'Current Record' && this.param2 === 'None') {
      location.href="this.ReportUrl & fv0 =this.param1";      
     } else if (this.param1 === 'Current Record' && this.param2 === 'Current User'){
      location.href="this.ReportUrl & fv0 =  this.param1  & fv1 =this.param2";
     } else if (this.param1 ==='Current User' && this.param2 === 'None'){
      location.href="this.ReportUrl & fv0 = this.param1";
  }
```

}
 }